# Splunk - How do I make a clickable hyperlink

Tags: splunk, splunk-query, splunk-dashboard

If the event has a URL and you want to show the URL in a search table where you can make the URL a clickable link that will go to that URL how do you do this?
for now, I'm doing this:

```
<drilldown>
     <link target="_blank">$row.URL|n$</link>
</drilldown>
```

and it's working , but that's make all of my row to lead into this link, and i want that only when you click on the specific URL it will lead you to this link

[image]

Comment: Curious - what's wrong with having the *row* click trigger going to the URL listed in the specific *field*? If you want, you can have the drilldown only fire on the specific field

Comment: Let's say I want each row will have some different URLs in different cols.
one will lead to the process link and one will lead to the application of the process link etc...
just to have more functionality

Answer (score 0):

To allow the user to click on a URL and be taken to that link, use `$click.value2|n$` as the drilldown target.

```
<drilldown>
     <link target="_blank">$click.value2|n$</link>
</drilldown>
```

There's an example in the Splunk Dashboard Examples app (https://splunkbase.splunk.com/app/1603)

Comment: yes, but now all the columns become links even those that are not URLs, I want that just a specific column will be linked to the URL because it's values are URLs, and the other can be regular text \ links to search.

Comment: Set the `drilldown` option in the `<table>` element to 'cell'.  `<table>... <option name="drilldown">cell</option>...</table>`

Comment: it's already in the cell, but the link is working in the column 'URL' in other columns, it also refers to the link and URL and then navigates me to some 404 page,  is there an option that only the URL column will be the referee as a link and the other will refer as text \ search. 
I added some images to the question.  with the xml

Comment: I think I understand the problem better.  To ensure the URL is used as a drilldown no matter which cell is clicked, go back to using `$row.URL|n$` as the drilldown target.  I'm not aware of a way to have different (or no) drilldowns for each cell in a row.

Comment: do you have an idea where I can figure out if this option is optional?

Comment: All of the options are documented in the Dashboards and Visualizations manual at https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/9.0.3/Viz/Aboutthismanual